# Finding value of functions $f(x) g(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions

If $f(x)=2x^3+4x^2+3x+2$ and $g(x)=2x^3+x^2+4$, where $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ then $f(x) g(x)$ is equal to ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : When you're multiplying 2 polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}[x]$, multiply them like you normally do, and in the resulting polynomial, just replace the coefficients with the representative of their residue class modulo $n$.

For example. if after multiplying two polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ you obtain $4x^6 + 10x^5 $, then the answer will be $4x^6$ as $10 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$

Comment: But isn't also $x^6 = x^2 \mod 5$?